# Reference to wrong appendix

Tags: pdf, labels, appendices, ref

In my report I have quite a lot of appendices (pdf's). 
I want to refer to them as A.1, A.2.....and so on
It all works fine for A , B and C, but when i refer to any appendix under C, the refrence in the output pdf is printed as C.3.

In the code I use `\ref{appendix:....}`

```
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\noappendicestocpagenum
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Vedlegg}
\addappheadtotoc
\includepdf[pages=1, pagecommand={\section{A}\label{appendix:A}},linktodoc=true]{A.pdf}

\newpage

\includepdf[pages = 1, scale = 0.72, fitpaper=true, pagecommand ={\section{B}\label{appendix:B}}, linktodoc = true]{B.pdf}

\newpage

\section{C}
\subsection{C.1}
\label{appendix:C.1}
\includegraphics[scale = 2]{C.1.jpg}
\newpage


\subsection{C.2}
\label{appendix:C.2}
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{C.2.jpg} 
\end{center}

\newpage

\subsection{C.3}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.9]{C.3.jpg}\label{appendix:C.3}  


\newpage
\includepdf[pages = 1, scale = 0.65, fitpaper=true, pagecommand ={\section{D}\subsection{D.1}\label{appendix:D.1}}, linktodoc = true]{D.1.pdf}
\newpage

\includepdf[pages = 1, scale = 0.72, fitpaper=true, pagecommand ={\subsection{D.2}}\label{appendix:D.2}, linktodoc = true]{D.2.pdf}
```

Comment: I had the labels outside pagecomand{}.., Problem soved

Answer (score 1):

I had the labels outside `\pagecomand{...}`. Problem soved!

Comment: Your code example has all the `\label`s within the `\pagecommand`. So, how does this answer help?

Comment: Not if you look at D.2, i noticed that i got the right reference at D.1, but from D.2 and down they all said C.3

Comment: Riiight. I missed that one. I'll delete my comments.